# CONNECT BY never ending

Tags: sql, oracle, connect-by

I've got a little trouble with a recursion using Oracle START WITH / CONNECT BY.

Given a table `id_string`, `id`, `ordre`, `prec` with `id_string` being a concatenation of `id_ordre`. and `prec` the link between two elements  having the same `id` (`1_1,1,1,2` is linked to `1_1,1,2,null`).
The table contains 500 rows with 196 unique `id_string`.

I want to retrieve all the linked rows from this table given starting with `id_string` equals `id|| '_' || ordre` and linked through `ordre` and `prec`, I use the following request

```
SELECT tda.*
FROM T_DRU_ALL tda
START WITH tda.ID|| '_' || tda.ORDRE = tda.id_string
CONNECT BY NOCYCLE PRIOR tda.ORDRE = tda.PREC and tda.id_string = tda.id_string
order by 1,2,3
```

My problem is very simple, the select has been running for one hour and is still running :'(
I'm sure there is something wrong in my code but I don't know where.

data file https://pastebin.com/R66T3hAu

Comment: A CONNECT BY is how Oracle does recursion.  And recursion happens when a function calls itself till there's no reason to call it.  So it's like a LOOP.  Ask yourself, does your loop have a reason to exit?  You can test browser recursion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54464162/4003419)

Comment: @APC the raw data contains 500 rows,I used pastebin to avoid flloding the post :)

Comment: @LukStorms the recursion ends when there is no couple ID,PREC in the table, so yes, it should stops (but as it didn't I could be wrong)
If I put the PRIOR on the right parts of the connect (tda.ORDRE = PRIOR tda.PREC) it ends with the 196 rows (the starting point of my recursion)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing a `PRIOR`, which is probably where your cycles were coming from and why you added `NOCYCLE`; without it, `tda.id_string = tda.id_string` is always true.

So at first glance you could just change:

```
CONNECT BY NOCYCLE PRIOR tda.ORDRE = tda.PREC and PRIOR tda.id_string = tda.id_string
```

or remove the `NOCYCLE`:

```
CONNECT BY PRIOR tda.ORDRE = tda.PREC and PRIOR tda.id_string = tda.id_string
```

<strike>But, that still never ends; curiously just rearranging the terms to what appears to be the same logical outcome works (but to me scans better anyway):</strike>

or rearrange the terms (which scans better to me, but shouldn't have any practical effect - not sure why I thought I saw one earlier!):

```
CONNECT BY tda.id_string = PRIOR tda.id_string AND tda.PREC = PRIOR tda.ORDRE
```

which now works OK:

```
ID_STRING         ID      ORDRE       PREC
--------- ---------- ---------- ----------
7682_2          7682          2
7682_2          7682         13          2
7682_2          7682         14         13
7690_6          7690          6
7690_7          7690          7
7693_2          7693          2
7693_2          7693          9          2
7693_2          7693         10          9
...

371 rows selected.
```

Personally I'd probably make the starting condition

```
START WITH tda.PREC IS NULL
```

rather than concatenating the values - it's the same result with the data you have, anyway.

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=9fe4787857bea4edf32b6c291326e504) (which you could supply in future with sample data if there's that much of it; or provide a much smaller sample that shows the issue...)

Comment: thanks a lot, it solves my problem perfectly. To summarize the answer, the problem came from a missing PRIOR in the CONNECT BY statement, I'll store it in my head :)